# Error I have gotten a few times and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-1.8

I keep seeing undefined `(?...)` sequence: something. For this particular one I had..

```
/(?<!\d)[0-3]?\d(?!\d)/
```

but this has happened a few times to me and I'm not sure how to fix it.

These always work in rubular, but then i get that error when I run it?

Help please!

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far.

Comment: It would help if you could explain what you are trying to accomplish with your regex.  I see a negative lookbehind and a negative lookahead, both involving a single digit.  An example with your desired result would be very helpful.  Please elaborate by editing rather than trying to do so in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its working here :

```
rituraj@rituraj:~$ irb
2.1.1 :001 > s = "somestring 23 and 34 and 233"
 => "somestring 23 and 34 and 233" 
2.1.1 :002 > s.scan(/(?<!\d)[0-3]?\d(?!\d)/)
 => ["23", "34"]
```

check your ruby version:

Ruby's regex engine doesn't support lookbehind which is less than 1.9.

You'd need to switch to 1.9+.

optional usage :  you can use [oniguruma](http://oniguruma.rubyforge.org/)

Comment: @hwnd aw sorry i thought people will get it from the ruby version.

Comment: This might be a dumb question but how do I change my ruby version?

Comment: @user3606254 how have you installed your ruby ? using rvm ?